# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QtWidget'

Tags: python, pyqt5

I installed the PyQt5 and Python3.4.
But When I built my program, I got an error message.

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QtWidget'

How can I solve this problem?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context,text)

class Ui_Form(QtGui.QtWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(Form)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.PrintHam_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.PrintHam_btn.setObjectName("PrintHam_btn")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.PrintHam_btn)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Super Ham"))
        self.PrintHam_btn.setText(_translate("Form", "Print Ham"))
        self.PrintHam_btn.clicked.connect(self.printHam)

    def printham(self):
        print ("Ham!")

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QtGui.QApplication (sys.argv)
        ex = Ui_Form()
        ex.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

it's my code. I have no idea why it's said there's no QtWidgets

Comment: I wrote the code, from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, Qtwidgets
then, Pycharm underline these and it's said has an error like,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QtWidget'
I installed PyQt5, so QtWidget is already installed and I checked that QtWidget folder is on the C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\sip\QtWidgets.
I don't know what I have to do to solve this problem. :(

Comment: I've editted it. Sorry, It's my first time to use this site

Answer (score 3):

The first mistake you are making is to edit the module compiled by `pyuic`. Never, ever, do this. Always import the module into your main application, so that you can re-compile it whenever necessary.

A lot of the classes that were in the `QtGui` module in Qt4 have moved to the `QtWidgets` module in Qt5. There are also other classes (like `QString`) that are no longer available in PyQt5.

It looks like your example code was compiled with `pyuic4`, and so you cannot use it with PyQt5. You need to re-compile it with `pyuic5`.

(There is also a typo in your example code. There is no such class as `QtWidget`: you probably meant `QWidget`. But fixing that is not enough. You must re-compile the module with `pyuic5` to fix all the problems).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that on this line:

```
class Ui_Form(QtGui.QtWidget):
```

You say `QtWidget` when it should say [`QWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html).

Comment: I think it's not a problem because I just typed someone's same code.
I installed on C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5
And QtWidget is in the PyQt5 folder